# Connect to on prem SQL server through Azure Databricks notebook using Python PYODBC

Tags: sql-server, azure-databricks

Currently I connect to my on premises SQL servers using Windows authentication. I would like to do the same using Databricks so that I can load the data extracted using the query into a dataframe  and do some machine learning experiments. Is it possible to connect to  sql server (on-prem) using pyodbc or any other driver in  notebooks?

Currently I am trying this code to connect to server database using databricks notebooks and I run into a connection timeout error

```
cxn=pyodbc.connect("Driver ={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};""Server=server name;"
"Port=1433;"Database=database_name;"Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```

If its a login issue is the solution to connect my databricks cluster to my network? If not it would be great if somebody  can point me in right direction.